# communicate to a client/server application in R

Tags: r, basex

Is it possible to communicate to a client/server application by calling the command System in R?
I use BaseX for storing xml databases and I want to call a Basex client from R by using the "system"command after have launching the basexserver manually

```
setwd("C:/Program Files/BaseX/bin/")
system("basexclient -U admin -P admin",wait = TRUE)
BaseX 8.1 [Client]
Try help to get more information.
```

The problem is that R can't communicate with the BaseX Client, and as consequence i get this error :

```
Child process not responding.R will terminate it.
```

I tried to change `wait` parameter to `wait=FALSE` and then execute a command BaseX but it seems that it can't communicate to the client also.

```
system("OPEN mydatabse",wait = FALSE)
object "mydatabse" not found
```

Any suggestions you can provide will be appreciated.

N.B : The same problem occurs with Java

Comment: basex has a full [REST API](http://basex.org/products/server/) why not just use it vs try to send commands and receive data through a cmd line piped process? or are you in standalone mode.

Comment: Can you create a file of instructions for BaseX and get the command line to run it, rather than trying to send one line at a time from R? You'll have to send any output to a file and read it from R afterwards. Obviously this is harder work if you want to do things conditional on responses from the external programme...

Comment: The advice given by @hrbrmstr seems on the point. Otherwise, of course you (or anyone else) could write a R client for BaseX, we would certainly be happy to have one. The server protocol is quite straightforward (http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Server_Protocol) and there are a number of clients available for other languages.

Comment: Thank you all for the ansewrs. @hrbrmstr I am using BaseX for storing xml database and R for analysis and I'm working in client mode.I have tried to solve the problem with Spacedman 's solution but it didn't work,Concerning REST API i don't really know how i can use it with R.